# Why is electric field independent of the surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration

I was studying about electric flux and Gauss' Law, and I saw the following case of a spherical surface
[image]

And the form to solve the problem where I saw that is

$$\begin{align*}
\iint_S\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}&=\iint_SE\;\cos(0)\;dA\\
&=\iint_SE\;dA\\
&=E\iint_SdA\quad*\\
&=4\pi R^2E
\end{align*}$$

But when I compute the surface integral using the traditional way (parametrizing the function):

$$\begin{align*}
\iint_S\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=\iint_S\vec{E}[\vec{S}(u,v)]\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\vec{S}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec{S}}{\partial v}\right)dudv
\end{align*}$$

The electric field *depends* on the *u* and *v* variables, but in * $||\vec{E}||$ doesn't depends on the surface so I can put outside of the integral. Obviously the first method is easier  than the second, but How we can explain the differences between the "dependences" of E over the surface?

Comment: The magnitude of $\vec E$ is constant at fixed radius from the charge, but the vector components are not. This is because $\vec E \propto \hat r$.

Comment: So, the more accurate concept is that, in this case $\vec{E}$ is independ of the dot product of $d\vec{A}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. The idea is that $\vec E$ is spherically symmetric, so $\vec E$ must be proportional to $\hat r$, $\vec E = E(r)\hat r$. If you then consider the integral  over a spherical surface $\iint \vec E\cdot d\vec A$, where $d\vec A=dA\hat r$, then the integrand $\vec E \cdot d\vec A = E(r) dA$ which is constant over the surface of a sphere.